# Can't set state after saving it to local storage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am implementing a search filter in my app and need to persist data between browser refreshes.

Here is my code:

```
    class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: shop,
    direction: {
      price: "asc",
      title: "asc"
    },
    searchTitle: "",
    searchPrice: {
      min: null,
      max: null
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const state = {
      searchTitle: this.state.searchTitle,
      searchPrice: this.state.searchPrice,
      direction: this.state.direction
    };

    window.localStorage.setItem("saved_state", JSON.stringify(state));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const state = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("saved_state"));

    console.log(state);

    if (state) {
      this.setState({
        searchTitle: state.searchTitle,
        searchPrice: state.searchPrice,
        direction: state.direction
      });
    }
  }

  // PRICE SORT
  priceSort = key => {
    this.setState({
      data: shop.sort(
        this.state.direction[key] === "asc"
          ? (a, b) => parseFloat(a.data[key]) - parseFloat(b.data[key])
          : (a, b) => parseFloat(b.data[key]) - parseFloat(a.data[key])
      ),
      direction: {
        [key]: this.state.direction[key] === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      }
    });
  };

  // OLD PRICE SORT
  oldPriceSort = key => {
    this.setState({
      data: shop.sort(
        this.state.direction[key] === "asc"
          ? (a, b) => parseFloat(a.data[key]) - parseFloat(b.data[key])
          : (a, b) => parseFloat(b.data[key]) - parseFloat(a.data[key])
      ),
      direction: {
        [key]: this.state.direction[key] === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      }
    });
  };

  // TITLE SORT
  titleSort = key => {
    this.setState({
      data: shop.sort(
        this.state.direction[key] === "asc"
          ? (a, b) => a.data[key].localeCompare(b.data[key])
          : (a, b) => b.data[key].localeCompare(a.data[key])
      ),
      direction: {
        [key]: this.state.direction[key] === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      }
    });
  };

  // TITLE FILTER
  updateTitleSearch = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchTitle: event.target.value
    });
    this.titleSearch();
  };

  titleSearch = () => {
    if (this.state.searchTitle) {
      this.setState({
        data: shop
          .filter(item => {
            return (
              item.data.title
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(this.state.searchTitle.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            );
          })
          .sort(
            this.state.direction.title === "asc"
              ? (a, b) => a.data.title.localeCompare(b.data.title)
              : (a, b) => b.data.title.localeCompare(a.data.title)
          )
      });
    }
  };

  // PRICE FILTER
  updateMinSearchPrice = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchPrice: { ...this.state.searchPrice, min: event.target.value }
    });
  };

  updateMaxSearchPrice = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchPrice: { ...this.state.searchPrice, max: event.target.value }
    });
  };

  priceSearch = () => {
    if (this.state.searchPrice.min || this.state.searchPrice.max) {
      this.setState({
        data: shop
          .filter(item => {
            return (
              parseFloat(item.data.price) >= this.state.searchPrice.min &&
              parseFloat(item.data.price) <= this.state.searchPrice.max
            );
          })
          .sort(
            this.state.direction.price === "asc"
              ? (a, b) => parseFloat(a.data.price) - parseFloat(b.data.price)
              : (a, b) => parseFloat(b.data.price) - parseFloat(a.data.price)
          )
      });
    }

    if (!this.state.searchPrice.max) {
      this.setState({
        data: shop.filter(item => {
          return parseFloat(item.data.price) >= this.state.searchPrice.min;
        })
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-container">
        <h1>Welcome to ShopMeNow!</h1>
        <Filters
          updateTitleSearch={this.updateTitleSearch}
          titleSearch={this.titleSearch}
          updateMinSearchPrice={this.updateMinSearchPrice}
          updateMaxSearchPrice={this.updateMaxSearchPrice}
          priceSearch={this.priceSearch}
        />
        <ItemTable
          data={this.state.data}
          priceSort={this.priceSort}
          oldPriceSort={this.oldPriceSort}
          titleSort={this.titleSort}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My aim is to fetch the saved data in the **componentDidMount()** hook. But it doesn't seem to work (i've already tried to console.log it)

What do I have to do in order to get it going? Thank you community!

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't seems to work"?

Comment: I mean it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you include your entire component, so we can see how you are updating your state etc.?

Comment: Just updated the code.

Comment: I'm sorry but replying just saying "it doesn work" means nothing for us to help you.
It's not updating your component as expected? Do you get a traceback error?

Comment: @LucaFabbri sorry i meant my filters are not saving their state after the refresh as expected

Comment: @doglabel please provide your render function, or a working example link

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting State in ComponentDidMount , why dont you create a entire different function and then call that function in ComponentDidMount.

All the Code of Setting State add in that function.
Try this and let me know if it works , Cheers !

```
    ComponentDidMount(){ 

       this.changeValues();

   }

   changeValues(){

     const state = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("saved_state"));

    console.log(state);

    if (state) {
      this.setState({
        searchTitle: state.searchTitle,
        searchPrice: state.searchPrice,
        direction: state.direction
      });
    }

   }
```

Comment: Hi! No it doesn't work.
The console.log, though, shows me that localStorage works well and everything is being saved to my state.
What the heck is wrong?

Comment: you don't have a constructor and you are also not using bind this.<methodname>.bind(this) - check this example 
 [link] (https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010) , it might help.

Comment: I'm using arrow functions which is the same. That's not where the problem lies.

The console.log messages show me that the state changes. But somehow the filters don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is you are saving data in localStorage inside componentDidUpdate and you are trying to get the data from local storage in componentDidMount.

You need to understand that componentDidMount called before componentDidUpdate which means you are reading the data from local storage before you set.

So you need to first set the data and then read data

Comment: Do you mean I should swap the code of componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate? I tried it but the app crashes.

Comment: It makes sense though... Guess I'm gonna go down the path you've offered... Gonna report about the results here. Thanks my man!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you're doing it in componentDidUpdate? If not, I would suggest moving that functionality to a separate function. The way things stand now, any update, including `this.setState`s on `data`, which you don't want to save to localStorage.

Perhaps you might consider writing a function that sets state and saves to localStorage, seeing as how your sort functions are already quite bulky.

Sample pseudocode:

```
setStateWithLocalStorage = newState => {
  const { searchTitle, searchPrice, direction } = this.state;
  this.setState(newState, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('saved_state', { searchTitle, searchPrice, direction })
  })
}
```

then you can use this function instead of `this.setState` on your sort functions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. Gonna check it out and report the results.